# Edit localStream

Tags: webrtc, getusermedia

Is there a way to edit the local video stream 'localStream' before sending it to another peer via peerConnection() ?

```
navigator.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true}, function(localMediaStream) {
var video = document.querySelector('video');

//How do I say edit a few pixes in the localMediaSttream before 
//using peerConnection() to    send it to another peer?
 }, onFailSoHard);
```

Answer (score 2):

*Here are a few assumptions for tomorrow!*

You can getUserMedia. Render stream in a video element. Use MediaSource APIs, get buffers; manipulate them. Do whatever you want!

Then capture stream from that "video" element.

It would be nice, if MediaSource APIs itself generate streams for us like WebAudio APIs.

Well, you can attach streams like this (after applying some affects on audio/video tracks):

```
peer.addStream ( new webkitStream (
    yourStream.audioTracks || yourStream.getAudioTracks(), 
    yourStream.videoTracks || yourStream.getVideoTracks() 
));
```

Comment: For tomorrow?  You can send the localStream to a MediaSource Object which can be manipulated before adding to the peer.addStream() ?

Comment: I meant that MediaSource APIs has limited support on chrome canary and/or Firefox. You can't capture pre-recorded medias today. For example; vide.captureStream() is a function should be implemented by browser vendors; but it is still in draft. Using FileReader APIs, you can get Array Buffers; convert them in blobs; convert those blobs to "typed" Uint8Array. Using those uint8Array, you can get predefined chunks of data. You can manipulate those chunks as you want. Good news is that you can play those chunks of data on video element. And then you can capture stream of/from that video element!